# Faster version of LINQ .Any() and .Count()

Tags: c#, linq

I'm checking if a list has an element whose source and target are already in the list. If not I'm adding that element to the list. I'm doing this way :

```
if (!objectToSerialize.elements
      .Any(x => x.data.source == edgetoAdd.data.source && 
                x.data.target == edgetoAdd.data.target))
      objectToSerialize.elements.Add(edgetoAdd);
```

This works but very slowly. Is there a way to make this part faster? Are there faster implementations of `Any()` or `Count`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you reason why there won't be a faster way to loop over all items than ... to loop over all items? You could stick them in a dictionary where `source` and `target` make up the key for faster lookup for example, but whether that's feasible depends on what your data structure looks like and what you actually want to do. It's nigh impossible to give relevant hints for optimization for this code snippet alone. Please read [ask] and properly explain what you're trying to do, including showing a [mcve].

Comment: Use a different data structure. Perhaps a dictionary keyed to a hash of source and target.

Comment: @Steve The identity of the value is based on *both* the source and the target, not just the target, so using just the source as the identity by making it the key would be wrong.

Comment: @Servy "hash of source and target"

Comment: @CodeCaster Then you have no value.  It should simply be a set.  There is no separate key and value.

Comment: @Servy Yeah, i said hash of source AND target.

Comment: @Steve At which point you have no value, so no need for a `Dictionary`.

Comment: @Servy Techically yes, he can use a hashset. But if he needs the reference to the element, he could use that as the value.

Comment: @Steve He could just as easily use that as the object in the set.  He has one object, and wants it to remain logically a set.  To do that you have a set of that object.  Tada.

Comment: Are you even sure the code you provided is slow? Not some other code? Did you use a profiler to determine what exactly makes your code run slow? Just to avoid *premature opimization*. Apart from this: why do you think there´s a faster approach on indicating if there´s an element matching a given condition when not looking *into* the objects within your list? Of course you have to loop your objects and check if they match, at least for *some* elements.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pre-index the data into something like a `HashSet<T>` for some `T`. Since you are comparing two values, a tuple might help:

```
var existingValues = new HashSet<(string,string)>(
    objectToSerialize.elements.Select(x => (x.data.source, x.data.target)));
```

now you can test

```
existingValues.Contains((edgetoAdd.data.source, edgetoAdd.data.target))
```

efficiently. But!! Building the index is not free. This mainly helps if you are going to be testing lots of values. If you're only adding one, a linear search is probably your best bet.

Note that you can use the index approach with an index that lasts between multiple `Add` calls, *but* you would also need to remember to `.Add` it to the index each time. You can short-cut the test/add pair by using the return value of `.Add` on the hashset:

```
if(existingValues.Add((edgetoAdd.data.source, edgetoAdd.data.target)))
{
    // a new value, yay!
    objectToSerialize.elements.Add(edgetoAdd);
}
```

Comment: Would another option be to change the elements property itself to be a HashSet ?